# Custom error message for invalid confirmation token in Devise for Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, rails-i18n

tl;dr:

Is there a non-hacky way to get a custom full error message for just one attribute (confirmation_token) and error (:invalid) combination on a single model (User in this case)? Or to override the message using Devise config?

Context

I'm working on a project in Rails 4 and I've been asked to change the error message Devise uses to tell the user that a registration confirmation token (part of a link included in the registration confirmation email) is invalid.

Devise has a nice Yaml config file to edit error messages, but this error does not seem to appear there. Looking into the code for Devise, it just creates a standard ':invalid' error on the confirmation_token field of the user model, rendered as a normal active record error (using errors.full_messages).

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/8e5c098e3aa53d6a72faadd8b929abaf2bb6d496/lib/devise/models/authenticatable.rb

(The method call resolves to `find_or_initialize_with_errors` with ':invalid' set as a default.)

I could monkey-patch Devise or fork the project, but that should be a last resort. Especially for what's basically a copy change.

I looked into using `en.yml` in the `config/locales` folder to set a custom message. Unfortunately, according to the Rails docs the error message format seems to be set globally:

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activemodel/lib/active_model/locale/en.yml#L4

so unless I'm mistaken, if I want to avoid starting the error message with 'Confirmation token' then I have to find all the possible full error messages that could be returned by any form submission and ensure they still make sense. Most would then say unhelpful things like " is invalid" or " cannot be blank".

Needless to say there are a lot of forms in this project, so that solution is out of scope for this bug-fix.

I could give the attribute a human name of `""` or `"The"` or something I suppose, but that could have a knock on effect elsewhere so is best avoided.

I've looked in vain for a way to limit the scope of the error message format string to a single attribute or model.

Presumably the "Rails way" is to override the full message in the validator, but that code is buried away in the gem in this case. The only ways I can think to get around this issue are hacky or fragile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok - here's what I did for now, aside from creating a PR on devise itself:

config/locales/en.yml

```
  devise:
    confirmations:
      header: 'Resend confirmation instructions'
    failure:
      confirmation_token_invalid: 'The confirmation link is no longer valid.  Please try sending a new confirmation email below.'
```

app/views/devise/confirmations/new.html.erb

```
<div id="confirmations-screen">
  <div class="dialog-head">
    <p><%= t('devise.confirmations.header') %></p>
  </div>

  <%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => confirmation_path(resource_name), :html => { :method => :post }) do |f| %>
    <% unless resource.errors.empty? %>
      <% resource.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
          <% if msg == 'Confirmation token is invalid' %>
            <%= t('devise.failure.confirmation_token_invalid') %>
          <% else %>
            <%= msg %>
          <% end %>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>

    <label for="email"><%= t('account.email.labels.email') %></label>
    <input type="email" id="user_email" name="user[email]" class="form-control">
    <button><%= t('devise.confirmations.resend_button') %></button>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Comment: That's a nice (still hacky, but workable) solution. I worked a somewhat similar hack into the error display in the view, but more of a general case using a prefix in the error message in the locale file to tell the view not to display the name of the field first.

To be fair this seems to be a problem with Rails and i18n rather than Devise.

Comment: But as this looks like it should work and you're the only response, have a green tick.

Comment: Looking at this again, while workable the following line: ```if msg == 'Confirmation token is invalid'``` would fail in other countries for a multi-language site.

Comment: Good point.  The hard part is that error is actually coming from ActiveModel - https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/3e36db4406beea32772b1db1e9a16cc1e8aea14c/activemodel/lib/active_model/locale/en.yml#L12 .  The part I'm unsure about is how/if/where the "Confirmation token" part of the message gets localized.  Would be worth testing, but if it doesn't get localized, then one could use `if msg == "Confirmation token #{t('errors.messages.invalid')}"`

Comment: You'd have to translate 'Confirmation token' itself, but yes.

I can't remember if Rails takes word order into account for different languages. That could also complicate the issue. ;)